# VBA issue with creating pivot cache

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic-pivot

I am struggling to find a solution to the issue I am having; I've been looking all over. I'm not sure if it is how I am obtaining my first row or if it is something else. I have the exact same code (below) setup for another macro but that macro pulls R1C1:lastrow/lastcol. The only difference is: this macro attempts to use a dynamic first row (instead of `Set PRange = glData.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)`) . I've even tried setting the first row as R10C1(the header row of the source data) and I still get an "Application-defined or object-defined error".

Macro use: Creates pivot table based on source data in range A(y):N(x); x = dynamic lastrow/col, y = dynamic first row. Destination is 4 columns to the right of another pivot table(created by a different sub). They will not overlap (unless something is hidden). I have made this setup manually and it works fine.

Any help is appreciated.

```
Sub CreateFAPiv()
'


Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim wsData As Worksheet: Set wsData = Sheets("Data")
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim asset As String
Dim glData As Worksheet: Set glData = Sheets("GL")

asset = glData.Range("B2").Value


Set PSheet = Worksheets("Piv")


'Define Data Range
FirstRow = IIf(IsEmpty(glData.Range("C1")), glData.Range("C1").End(xlDown).Row, 1)
LastRow = glData.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = glData.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = glData.Cells(FirstRow, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)


'Define Pivot Cache - This is where I am getting the error
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(3, 4), _
TableName:="DataPivotTable")


'Insert Blank Pivot Table
Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(3, 4), TableName:="DataPivotTable")


.....Rest of code....


End Sub
```

Comment: Remove the `. _
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(3, 4), _
TableName:="DataPivotTable")
`. The creation of the pivot table happens in the next line: `Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable...`

Comment: Now I get a "Method 'CreatePivotTable' of object 'PivotCache' failed" message.

Comment: Okay. I realized the error of my ways. I was naming the pivot table the same name as the previous one (since I copied the code).